# How can I setup Minitest fixtures to test Apartment using postgres schemas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures, minitest, apartment-gem

I am building a multi tenant app in Rails using the Apartment Gem and Postgresql 9.4.1.

I use Minitest and dont' know RSpec.

How can I setup Minitest fixtures to put some fixtures/data in the public schema and some other data in a specific schema?

**Example:** Accounts is my non schema table, the rest goes in a schema.
I have tried to setup my fixtures to prefix the schema name like so:

- accounts.yml
- schema1.users.yml
- schema1.projects.yml

This just fails with a:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "schema1.customers" does not exist
```

So it is trying to put the data into the correct schema, the schema just doesn't exist.

It looks like I  need a way for to build the tenants/schemas when the test DB is migrated or first built, something like:

```
Apartment::Tenant.create('schema1')
```

and then the normal minitest preload will put the fixtures data into the appropriate schema.

Not sure on where/when/how this needs to happen.

Any ideas?